# Weighted random choice with categories

Tags: python, django

So basically I have a database table with photos. Each photo has a rating <0,1> and categories (one or more). I need a way to efficiently chose x elements from this table at weighted random but with respect to categories, I have to do this in python3 + Django (or microservice communicating thru Redis or exposing RESTapi).

eg:
table:

```
.---------.--------.------------.
|  photo  | rating | categories |
:---------+--------+------------:
| Value 1 |    0.8 | art, cats  |
:---------+--------+------------:
| value 2 |    0.5 | cats       |
:---------+--------+------------:
| value 3 |    0.9 | night      |
'---------'--------'------------'
```

And when I ask for 1 photo with categories (cats, dogs). The algorithm should return something like

`numpy.random.choice([Value 1, Value 2], 1, [0.8, 0.5], replace=False)`

Currently, every time I am asked for it I do something as follow:

```
photos = Photos.objects.filter(category__in=[list of wanted categories])
photos, weights = zip(*list(photos.values_list('photo', 'rating')))
res = numpy.random.choice(photos, amount_wanted, weights, , replace=False)
```

Is there more efficent approach to this? I can use any AWS service to achive it.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use something like

```
photo = random.sample(Photos.objects.filter(category__in=[list of wanted categories], rating__gte=random.random())), 1)
```

This line basically selects all categories you want, filters out entries according to their probability, and returns a random one.

Comment: From what I found out `.order_by('?')` is super slow.
`Note: order_by('?') queries may be expensive and slow, depending on the database backend you’re using.`
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#order-by

Comment: I like the solution, but I think order by '?' is slow as well. You could have python take a random entry from the result set (integer between 0 and result set count) and it will be a lot faster I think.

Comment: I updated the solution to use `random.sample` instead of `order('?')`.